# selenium python why I am not getting image url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get all gallary image url from this [page](https://www.morilee.com/product/quinceanera-dresses/vizcaya/iridescent-crystal-beaded-quinceanera-dress/). Every product have multiple images. here is my code where I am trying to get image url:

```
img = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gem-gallery-thumbs-carousel img')
for i in img:
    y = i.get_attribute('href')
    print(y)

result:     
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Images typically have a `src` attribute, not `href`.  And on that page in particular, it looks like they have a `data-tgpli-src` attribute.

Comment: John Gordon I know and tried but didn't work

Comment: Update the question to include a sample of the element you are expecting to find.

Comment: John Gordon Thanks. it worked now after changing `href` to `src` but didn't understood why it wasn't working before. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The image urls in those elements are contained in `src` attribute, not in `href` as mentioned in comments.
2. You probably should add wait / delay to make the page loaded before reading the elements contents.
   So, something like this **After** appropriate wait / delay should work:

```py
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gem-gallery-thumbs-carousel img')
for img in imgs:
    url = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

To output the srcs for those you need to .get_attribute() for src

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('https://ca.morilee.com/product/quinceanera-dresses/vizcaya/iridescent-crystal-beaded-quinceanera-dress/')
imgs=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".gem-gallery-thumbs-carousel img")))
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute("src")
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

```
https://ca.morilee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2021/11/89331-0259-scaled-1-280x400.jpg
https://ca.morilee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2021/11/89331-0292-scaled-1-280x400.jpg
https://ca.morilee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2021/11/89331-0061-scaled-1-280x400.jpg
https://ca.morilee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2021/11/89331-0083-scaled-1-280x400.jpg
https://ca.morilee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2021/11/89331-0101-scaled-1-280x400.jpg
https://ca.morilee.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2021/11/89331-0196-scaled-1-280x400.jpg
```